# Heroku Prevent Python Django Objects from being uploaded

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

So I have a programming forum site, with users, threads, and responses that they post (these are all objects). However, everytime when I deploy a new version using:

```
git push heroku master
```

, it resets all of the users, threads, and responses to what I have on my local machine. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you avoiding migrations files to be pushed to your git branch?

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: You were saying your database values are getting reset right?

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran Yeah. The users, threads, and comments are reset to what I have on my local machine.

Comment: If i am not wrong you are using sqilte as you backend and you are pushing your database to git

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran yes

Comment: There you go.. Please avoid pushing your DB to you git braches. Maintain two seperate DB one in local and in prod. This will make sure that your data doesn't get replace all time. :). I hope this helps you

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran So how would I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109876/discussion-between-niranj-rajasekaran-and-devhaven-herokuapp-com).